# access token LinkedIn API

Tags: rest, authentication, linkedin-api, access-token

For a school project I need access to LinkedIn API. 
I have already created an app on LinkedIn Developers. However, when I do a GET request to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization, I am not able to **get an access token**, and I get "you need to pass the scope"
Even though the documentation specified that the scope field is optional, I added scope=scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social at the end of my request and got a "invalid scope error".
As for the redirect uri field, I am not sure what to put (can I put a random website URL?)

**If someone knows the solution to that problem or know other ways to get an access token**, I would be very grateful :) Thank you !

Kim

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a redirect URI in order to get a valid access token.

First step:

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=YOURCLIENTID&redirect_uri=https://my.webserver.com

Once you login and confirm LinkedIn will redirect you to the provided redirect URI with the code parameter. The next step is to exchange this code for an access token.

Second step:

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=CODE&redirect_uri=https://my.webserver.com&client_id=YOURCLIENTID&client_secret=YOURCLIENTSECRET

If everything is valid LinkedIn will again redirect to the provided redirect URI, but this time with the access token.

Hope it helps.

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. I don't understand what the redirect URI should be ? Is it a website I put online by myself or a random web page from the Internet ?
Thank you.

Kim

Comment: Most of the time it's the exact location that you start the oAuth request from. If this is a development environment you could also use localhost (127.0.0.1).

You can not use a random URL for this, because LinkedIn will redirect the the user in the browser to this URL. You will need to catch that redirect because you need the code to exchange it for the access token.