# Generating access tokens for LinkedIn API

Tags: http, linkedin-api

I need to generate the access tokens for my application. I followed the steps on [access token LinkedIn API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680733/access-token-linkedin-api)

I got the `code` value after the first step. When I used this code value in the second step in this url: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=CODE&redirect_uri=https://my.webserver.com&client_id=YOURCLIENTID&client_secret=YOURCLIENTSECRET , I got an error saying

`{"error":"invalid_redirect_uri","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"}`

I am sure my `redirect_uri = http:localhost:8080/code` is correct because it's the same that I used in the first step. Someone kindly help me out.

Thanks

-Sahib

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is in the error message. The access token request url has a different redirect url. Check the url for the parameter `redirect_uri`:

**redirect_uri=https://my.webserver.com**

`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=CODE&redirect_uri=https://my.webserver.com&client_id=YOURCLIENTID&client_secret=YOURCLIENTSECRET`

Try replacing this with you local server address and port as you have listed in your original post, `redirect_uri = http:localhost:8080/code`